# как передать данные на страницу и потом открыть ее с этими данными? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Мне нужно передать данные на страницу и потом перейти на эту же страницу. В первом случае у меня переходит при нажатии кнопки, но переменная time не успевает обновиться в методе onClickOrder. Во втором случае я просто не знаю как передать на страницу перед ее открытием.  Подскажите как правильно это сделать?

```
<Link to=
              {{
                pathname:"/finish",
                propsFinish:50+time
              }}
              >
                <Button 
                 onClick={onClickOrder} 
                  className="pay-btn">
                  <span>Оплатить сейчас</span>
                </Button>
              </Link>
```

или так

```
    time= (count*15)/(x*q);
 

       window.open("/finish");
```

Comment: Вы хотите через router передать?

Comment: +NavLink или Link просто меняет то что в адресной строке Route слидит за сменой адресной строки и загружает какой то компонент который соответствует указанному пути https://learn-reactjs.ru/training-project/routing

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через query параметры, или посмотрите в сторону redux.

```
window.open(`/finish?time=${time}`);
```